# How to fix App Store connect displaying Unauthorized Access error in fastlane

Tags: app-store-connect, fastlane, bitrise

I am getting an Unauthorized Access error when my app is logging into App Store connect.  When I open up App Store connect within my browser as the company account I can't see any references to permissions etc to give permission.  Can anyone please help?  This has worked before but I can't see any hints of where something needs to be given permission.

Thanks

[image: Unauthorized Access log out]

**Update**

[image: Bitrise Workflow Editor screen shot]

**Update**

[image: upload_to_app_store]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your password and sign out of all devices then try again with the new password.

https://appleid.apple.com

Comment: thanks for this, I'm going to try this although I don't know how this relates to my build process in bitrise that uses fastlane?  thanks

Comment: Do you have a generic user for bitrise ? Do you use appStoreConnect API oder app specific password with fastlane session ?

Comment: I've added a screen shot of bitrise/ fastlane - are you referring to this user?  FASTLANE_USER and FASTLANE_PASSWORD - sorry I'm not familiar with bitrise/ fastlane

Comment: Yes, most probably your bitrise/fastlane user has no 2FA. "This has worked before", what does this exactly mean ?

Comment: thanks Nemanja, "this has worked before" referring to this isn't a demo project but it's for an existing company with active apps that were built and released previously through the same bitrise/ fastlane setup - hope that adds some context

Comment: let me know if there's anything else you need to know

Comment: So you can build the app, but you cannot upload it ? 
Do you use appStoreConnect API ? 
Do you have 2FA ?

Comment: Yes it looks like the app is build, just access denied to the app store

Comment: we're using "Apple Service connection" in bitrise

Comment: I searched for it now - please try to use ´API key authentication´, if you still use ´Apple ID authentication´. It is recommended. Documentation about this -> https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/connecting-to-services/setting-up-connection-to-an-apple-service-with-api-key/
General documentation -> https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/connecting-to-services/configuring-bitrise-steps-that-require-apple-developer-account-data/